# What is the time complexity for finding the maximum value less than a given value?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Any data structure that I know of which orders data, has, at best, an O(log n) lookup.

I argue that to find the maximum value less than a given value, we need to first discover where that given value would live in the data structure. (I have no proof that this is a required first step).

That requires O(log n) time.

From there, we need to find the maximum value less than that. In the case of an array, we look one index back O(1). In the case of a balanced tree, we traverse a path which is typically O(log n).

In any case, it seems the average total time complexity must be O(log n).

Is that correct, or can we somehow do better?

Comment: I think it is typical binary search problem, so `O(logn)`

Comment: What are the values? Can we assume that they are in a limited range? Are you allowed to perform precomputation(which would make sense only if you perform many such queries)? Also second question is kind of pointless - you can always do worse :)

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev got rid of the worse part.

Comment: @z5h actually this was the most important part of my comment just kind of teasing. Could you please answer the questions?

Comment: One could imagine a data structure with a O(1) lookup of a specific value and a O(log(n)) search - for instance a combined hashmap / tree. You could then do a speculative lookup of the max value. If you're lucky you can then do the whole search in O(1) (best case).

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev re precomputation. Isn't using a data structure already a precomputation in the sense that it required work to build? Suppose the values are limited to n-bit numbers for some arbitrary n.

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling Nice. Your solution is good, but only if the key value exists in the hashmap. Thanks.

Comment: @z5h: You can also afford retrying for lower values a couple of times. In fact, you could expand this idea to add entries for all missing objects pointing to the closest existing object with a lower value. This way you pay a bit when inserting but are guaranteed a hit on lookup. Only works for enumerable ranges though I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no more efficient comparisons based algorithm. Worst case is indeed bounded by `Omega(logn)` using comparisons based algorithms, since there are `n` possible outputs (all of them can be achieved given the correct query), and to choose one of them the computation tree must be of height `log(n)`. This gives us a lower bound of `Omega(logn)` for this problem using comparisons, regardless of the data structure used.

This bound is obviously tight, since in a sorted array, one can find the desired value using binary search in `O(logn)`.

Answer (score 2):

If your values are limited to a reasonable range, and there are no restrictions on the complexity of building the data structure in the first place, you can do it in O(1) by using a classic time/space tradeoff.

Simply keep an array large enough for all possible input values. Initialize it with a value that indicates there is no valid maximum. To insert a new value, fill every array element *above* that number with the number, until you reach an element that already contains a different maximum. After you're finished, getting a maximum is as easy as getting the value at the array index.

In Python, for any value `0` to `n_max`:

```
array = [None] * (n_max + 1)
for n in values:
    for i in range(n + 1, n_max + 1):
        if array[i] == i - 1: break
        array[i] = n

for n in lookups:
    print array[n]
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick answer, yes it must be O(logn) because you need the order of the data to be able to compare your value with the data and see that indeed there is nothing else closer and below your value than the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answering a more practical problem: **Find the maximum value less than x, for every x in a sorted array**.

Let's say the collection of maximum values has size `n` and the array of x to look up has size `m`.

Optimising each subproblem separately, i.e. iteration over x `O(m)` times search for the value `O(logn)`, the best you can do is `O(m*logn)`.

But this practical problem can be solved in `O(m+n)` - iff both arrays are already sorted, it's just a matter of iterating over both arrays concurrently.. Obviously makes sense only if `m > n` and constant factors might be more important for a particular size.